# Apache ScriptAlias unable to set Script parameter

Tags: linux, apache2, apache

I'm porting over a Windows httpd.conf file to a linux apache server. I'm pretty much done, but the only error i get is:

```
 * Starting web server   apache2                                                                                    [Tue Feb 07 14:24:34 2012] [warn] The Alias directive in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf at line   449 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
Syntax error on line 461 of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'Script', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in  the server configuration
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

My httpd.conf file at line 461 is as follows:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin "/var/www/cgi-bin"

Script PUT /cgi-bin/put.py
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the `mod_actions` [module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_actions.html) isn't loaded. This module enables the use of `Script`s.
If you activate this module, the error message should disappear.

You can typically activate `mod_actions` by creating a symlink from the respective `mods_available` directory like this:

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/actions.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/actions.load
```

The directory structure can be different on your machine, but the principle remains the same: There are available modules and these can be activated by symlinking into the `mods_enabled` dir.

Comment: how do I activate the module?

Comment: http://www.beardy.se/exchanging-apache2-mpm-prefork-for-apache2-mpm-worker-and-using-php5-cgi-on-debian-to-improve-performance found it here, nevermind